# Bitbucket says the branch is merged, but the code is missing and git has no record of the merge

Tags: git, bitbucket

One member of my team created a branch and made some code changes there. He then created a pull request in bitbucket for his branch. After couple of days, he approved the pull request and Merged it to the main branch via bitbucket. So now bitbucket says that the branch is merged, but when I go to the main branch, the code isn't there. And bitbucket still says that it's merged.

I thought that someone by error reverted those changes, but I checked in Git history and there is no record at all of this commit, so that's not it. What's going on? I'm really worried that this has happened for other branches as well, that we've closed them thinking they are merged when in fact they weren't.

Answer (score 0):

That should only happen if the merge was done with the `--ours` option.

It would ignore any change coming from the source branch, while recording a merge.

Comment: But even if the merge was done with the --ours option, it would still be shown in git, and now it is not. Plus there were no conflicts in the file the changes were written.

Comment: @petko_stankoski then there must have been a push --force overriding the history on BitBucket. The PR merge event is still there, but the history might have changed.

Comment: But the push was done via Bitbucket, after you Approve the pull request and then click Merge, it automatically also pushes. Is it possible that Bitbucket made a forced push?

Comment: @petko_stankoski no, I meant, after the PR got accepted, an unrelated git push --force initiated from any other client could have overridden the merged history.